# What is the meaning of a P100 score in image recognition / categorization?

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition, image-processing, computer-vision

I've seen it used in a couple papers, none of which are freely available, but a preview gives a couple sentences involving a P100 score here: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=p100+score&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C33&as_vis=1 and in the abstract here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.08088

What is the meaning / derivation of a P100 score, in machine learning image recognition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the papers is publicly available at [this address](http://lixirong.net/pub/mm2016-vsd.pdf).

From this paper, it seems to be an acronym designing an evaluation criterion:

> Evaluation criteria. Following the protocol [15], we report Average
>   Precision (AP), Precision at the top 10 ranked videos (P10), and P100.

This would mean that P100 holds for: Precision at the top 100 ranked videos.

This seems linked to the specific data set used in that paper. I do not think this is a common acronym for any type of scoring/performance quantity in image classification.